# Android- Cant get simple photo app working

Tags: android, gallery

I've just started learning some Android app development basics and i wanted to make an app that, upon tapping a button, lets you shoot and save a photo using the existing camera app.

I've followed [this](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) tutorial (using Android Studio) for the core code, and I've made my app. By the way, after shooting the photo, it wont save it into the gallery even if it should.

I've tried different variations on the code but none of those worked. In the logcat windows, while running the app, when i tap the button that open the camera i got this log ( which i don't really know whether if is infulent or not)

> 05-13 19:25:38.974 24578-24602/seba.fotoapp E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb99d9980

I'm running android 6.0 (API23)

Here's my code:

> MainActivity.java

```
package seba.fotoapp;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
// Storage Permissions
private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};

String mCurrentPhotoPath;
/**
 * Checks if the app has permission to write to device storage
 *
 * If the app does not has permission then the user will be prompted to grant permissions
 *
 * @param activity
 */
public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
    // Check if we have write permission
    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );
    }
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    Button take_picture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.take_picture);
    take_picture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    verifyStoragePermissions(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            galleryAddPic();
        }
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}

}
```

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="seba.fotoapp" >
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture an image and save it for sure, you need an Android capture intent (which you have). Instead of going to the `dispatchTakePictureIntent()`, run the intent directly.

In your button creation (onCreate):

```
Button take_picture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.take_picture);
take_picture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Creates an Intent to the camera
            Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            // ARGS: the intent, a key to access later
            startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
    }
});
```

Then use the `onActivityResult` method to open the camera:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && data != null) {
        try {
            Bitmap selectedImg = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            Log.i("Picture from Camera", "Captured");

            // Create a file to write bitmap data
            File f = new File(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), "image.png");
            f.createNewFile();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Do anything with either the Bitmap or the File that was created.

Answer (score 1):

Following the answer given by AkashBhave you may look at this code for saving images..

```
private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
myDir.mkdirs();
Random generator = new Random();
int n = 10000;
n = generator.nextInt(n);
String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
File file = new File (myDir, fname);
if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
try {
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
   finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
   out.flush();
   out.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```